# how to use stock charts and bar/pie in the same dashboard?

Tags: javascript, anychart

I'm using anychart and anystock - how can I use both stock charts and bar/pie in the same dashboard? I need to change data in stock chart by clicking to bar/pie chart sectors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can listen the chart "click" event and update stock using the selected chart data.

How to work with chart data in real-time: http://docs.anychart.com/7.8.0/Working_with_Data/Data_Manipulation

How to work with event listeners: http://docs.anychart.com/7.8.0/Common_Settings/Event_Listeners

James, we wil contact you via email to discuss this case in details.